# Str Object Not Callable Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm not familiar with the TypeError: 'str' object is not callable error. It's frustrating because this code has always worked up until today and I haven't changed anything directly related to this method.

Line that Python says is the culprit:

```
    start_date = date(2015, 5, 20)
```

Entire method: Pardon the chicken scratch comments.

```
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

#DOESN'T FETCH ALL THE DOMAINS FOR WHATEVER REASON
#Search for new domains, written by Todd
#1. add to a running set, 'grabbedDomains' 2. add output file for each day run 3. write to master CSV 
def domainSearch(search_term):
    """
    Function registrant_monitor_data_details provides searching over a range of dates, this allows script to be ran once a week or at whatever
    interval we need.  May or may not need de-duplicating, will find out during testing.
    """
    #Today's date; date of domains we're searching for
    start_date = date(2015, 5, 20)
    end_date = date(2015, 6, 26)
    #single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    #today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        results = client.registrant_monitor_data_details(date= single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), term=search_term)
        data = results['data']
        if type(data) is dict:
            for alert in results['data']['alerts']:
                print "{0} - {1}".format(alert['domain'], alert['created'])
                #Adds domains to the global set to be added to the case
                global domainList
                domainList.append("{0}".format(alert['domain']))
    #Gets domain details from DIPITS by date and search term (email address), RETURNS DICTIONARY

    #Prints search results, should be domains registered by search term
    print "LENGTH, ", len(domainList)

    return results
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? It's hard to figure out what's going on with just that one line.

Comment: How did you import [`date`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)? Do you have a variable named `date` somewhere that is shadowing this class?

Comment: I got it figured out, I assigned the global variable date to something at the top of the page.  I imported datetime & time though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere else in your code, you have assigned a string to `date`.

```
from datetime import date  # usual import
date(2015, 7, 8)  # this works
date = "hello"  # replace date with a string
date(2015, 7, 8)  # causes TypeError
```

Comment: Good call.  I assigned the global variable 'date' to something at the top of the page.  I fixed that and it works fine now, thank you!